# How can I prevent a JQueryUI Context menu from appearing underneath a PDF loaded into an IFrame in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, pdf, internet-explorer-9

This has been driving me up the wall. We are using a JQueryUI grid and a sub grid within it that expands and collapses. The main grid rows have context menus that drop down when the row is clicked. In this particular grid the expansion shows the PDF associated with a contract. Everything works fine until you try to invoke the context menu in which case it pops behind the PDF viewer. It's still clickable via an edge just off to the left of the viewer but I cannot get it to show up in front of the viewer. I've tried adjusting the z-index and I've also tried detaching the Iframe, as well as a Div wrapped around the Iframe, from the dom [a la this other stack overflow article.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690320/css-hover-menu-appearing-behind-pdf-iframe) but then the reader doesn't show up at all, most likely hidden behind the other elements i'm assuming.

Anyone have any ideas to hack this thing to work?

Comment: How is displayed the PDF in HTML?

Comment: do you have an example available online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF is being rendered by a plug-in.  I suspect that portion of the screen is "owned" by the Acrobat plug-in until you close that PDF.

It's not really even a z-order thing (if I'm right).  HTML may simply not be drawn within that rectangle.