# Iframe alternative for Microsoft Report viewer?

Tags: asp.net, iframe, reporting-services, reportviewer, report

Can the following code be rewritten to display ms report viewer without using iframe?

```
<iframe id="Iframe1" runat="server" src="Pdf.aspx" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="590" />

                    <rsweb:ReportViewer  ID="someid" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Visible="false"
                                   ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="100%" ShowDocumentMapButton="false" DocumentMapWidth="15%" DocumentMapCollapsed="True" HyperlinkTarget="_top">
                    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

this is an existing application and i don't want to break it, however because of using iframe css menus are getting blocked.

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar style of question with a decent answer:

[CSS hover menu appearing behind pdf iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690320/css-hover-menu-appearing-behind-pdf-iframe)

Otherwise, I presume you have tried changing z-index, positions of both items already>

I presumes "rewritten" you're implying to display the report outside the iframe inside the page's HTML. Well yes if you are using WebForms not MVC, but, even if WebForms there might be a reason the original didn't and from the detail you have given I cannot tell.