# Overlay effect working on iframe in Chrome but not in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a Document viewer with `.less` file having:

```
div.document-previewer-container {
//height: 400px;
//width: 300px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
//padding: 5px 2px;
> div.document-preview {
    height: 88%;
    //width: 100%;
    position: relative;

    .document-container, .text-container, video, iframe, pre {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .document-container > img {
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .text-container pre {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .doc-overlay {
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        top: 0;

        p {
            padding: 2px;
        }
    }
}
}
```

My html is

```
<div class="document-previewer-container">
<div class="document-preview">
    <h3 ng-click="vm.openPDF()">yu</h3> <----- THIS CLICK IS WORKING
    <div class="document-container">
        <!-- PDF show in iframe -->
    </div>
    <div class="doc-overlay" ng-click="vm.openPDF()"> <---- THIS CLICK ISN'T becuse if is hidden by iframe
        <!-- any content is shown on the top of PDF file in chrome only, not in IE -->
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My click event is working on  tag but not when clicked on div with css class 'doc-overlay'.

How to handle it

**I am using Foxit Reader plugin for IE11**

> Update1
>
> I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690320/css-hover-menu-appearing-behind-pdf-iframe) question which I think is happening with me. The iframe is overlapping `.doc-overlay` and hence the click isn't working.
> **Any suggestions for this please**

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a CSS issue. You have used SCSS format that is why DOM is unable to find class "doc-overlay".

You can use this CSS, it will work fine.

```css
div.document-previewer-container {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
div.document-previewer-container> div.document-preview {
    height: 88%;
    position: relative;
}
    div.document-previewer-container> div.document-preview .document-container, .text-container, video, iframe, pre {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    div.document-previewer-container> div.document-preview .document-container > img {
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

   div.document-previewer-container> div.document-preview .text-container pre {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

   div.document-previewer-container> div.document-preview .doc-overlay {
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        top: 0;
}
div.document-previewer-container> div.document-preview  .doc-overlay p {
       padding: 2px;
}
```