# IE hide the Menu Items when PDF is loaded on Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, iframe, internet-explorer-11

I've a menu item. When the user clicks on the menu item button (Claim) it opens the PDF below the menu item.

[image: Image of menu item]

Issue is when I loaded the same webform in Internet Explorer it opens
the PDF below the code but my menu item list goes behind the PDF.

[image: image of menu item behind the PDF iframe viewer]

Here is my code on how the PDF is loading on web form:

```
<iframe id="myframe" width="100%" height="600px" runat="server" frameborder="1" ></iframe>
```

I've used the **iframe** to load the PDF.

```
string fileName = "IGI-Travel-Sure-Claim-Procedure.pdf";
    this.myframe.Attributes["src"] = "../uploads/pdf/" + fileName;
```

Above code is when form is loaded then it loads the PDF on the web form.

My issue is that whenever I open my webfrom in internet explorer it hides my menu item list behind the iframe PDF viewer. Meanwhile same webform with same code and iframe works fine in all other browsers, like Chrome, FireFox, Opera and Edge too but not in Internet Explorer 11.
The application is developed in  **framework 2.0** Check this image

[This also help you to understand my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tur3r.png)

Comment: I'm new member so cannot add  **Direct Images** as per rule policy of StackOverFlow

Comment: this may be CSS issue. check this link . [click on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690320/css-hover-menu-appearing-behind-pdf-iframe?rq=1) . Hope it will help you. If still any other help required share your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but  I already done what they are discussing and applied the provided solutions. but yes my question matches the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for this question answer i dig very deep but some how I'm able to find it's answer.
Hopefully those have this problem can also resolve from my answer.

Applied simple CSS on my `<iframe>` to display the PDF.
The simple CSS applied is

```
 #Iframe-Master-CC-and-Rs {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* inner wrapper: make responsive */
.responsive-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;    /* gets height from padding-bottom */

  /* put following styles (necessary for overflow and scrolling handling on mobile devices) inline in .responsive-wrapper around iframe because not stable in CSS:
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: auto; */

}

.responsive-wrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

/* padding-bottom = h/w as % -- sets aspect ratio */
/* YouTube video aspect ratio */
.responsive-wrapper-wxh-572x612 {
  padding-bottom: 107%;

}
```

And here is the  code

```
<div class="responsive-wrapper responsive-wrapper-wxh-572x612">
<iframe src="yourpdflink.pdf" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
```

Now working fine on every browser if any still not resolve issue comment to discuss.